# Android GPS turns off after long period of time

Tags: android, mono, gps, location, alarmmanager

I have completed writing an android application (2.2+) using mono for android to track a devices location on 24/7 basis.

For the most part the application runs quite well however there seems to be an issue where the GPS will decide to simply turn itself off (icon disappears from notification bar) and not reengage.  This occurs randomly but happens roughly when app has been running for 24 hours.

I use an AlarmManager service to check if a GPS location update has been registered in last 10 minutes and if not restart the application.  Even on the restart of the application, the GPS will not reengage.  For the GPS to start tracking again for this application the phone has to restarted.

All my services start and stop as they should and drop the listeners on the locationManager when necessary.

Rather than show code I was inquiring if anyone else had come across the same issue where the GPS can simply decide to disable itself while it is being used in an application and not restart even on reopening the application.

Comment: Which phone are you testing this on. I had similar problem with wifi on Samsung. The cause was bug in the native service whihc stuck in a loop trying to restart itslef. I could find out cos I was working for them and had the complete OS

Comment: Current testing on Samsung Galaxy S3.  We use mobile network pass data back to server obviously as out on the road.  It is very random yes the GPS services decides to disappear without any reason.  If you have any information regarding any native OS details and Samsung really appreciate.